# How to convert a column value to an string array in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame in `pandas` has below data:

```
>>> df.head(5)
  currency code currency name
0           1ST    FirstBlood
1         2GIVE      GiveCoin
2           808       808Coin
3           ABT      ArcBlock
4           ABY       ArtByte
```

I wonder how I can convert the column `currency code` into a string array like `['1ST', '2GIVE', '808', 'ABT' ... ]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check

```
df['currency code'].tolist()
```